# I need help to interpret this headline

Tags: sentence-meaning, american-english

The headline is:

"SpaceX Carries NASA Astronaut Mission Home With Safe Water Landing"
--[New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/11/09/science/spacex-nasa-water-landing.html)

The way it is written it says SpaceX bring the mission home and not the astronauts, right?

I read through the link, but the only way it would make sense to me is:

"SpaceX Carries NASA Astronaut Home With Safe Water Landing"

I mean once they're home the mission is over right?

Comment: The _mission_ is the whole expedition; the headline means that the spacecraft came back to Earth safely with the astronauts inside it. If they had somehow been left behind in space, it would have been a very different headline!

Comment: What @kate said. Note that in the cited context, ***Astronaut*** is neither a "subject" nor "object" - it's a ***noun adjunct / attributive noun*** usage, adjectivally modifying the "head" noun ***Mission*** (which ***is*** the object of the verb ***carries** [home]*).

Comment: Does that implies that the Mission carry on on earth?

Comment: The return to Earth is the end of the mission.

Answer (score 0):

In aeronautics - and likely in other contexts too - the "mission" isn't just a list of objectives, but rather it incorporates everything involved. You will commonly hear that an individual is *part of* the mission.

So, returning 'the mission' safely implies the ship and crew were returned safely.